# C# .NET How can I show an image on WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

How can I show an image on a webbrowser control in C#/.NET? I'm doing something like

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><head></head><body><img src=imagelocationURL.png/></body></html>"
```

but the image doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is "imagelocationURL.html"? Also, you should put quotes around attribute values in HTML...

Comment: Could be http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/8/8a/20050801072301!Wikinews-logo.png 
I need to show png images from a certain location.

Comment: Sorry, on the example I meant .png. Edited

Answer (score 4):

I would guess one of two things:  either that, as codeka points out, you are missing the quotes (single or double) around imagelocationURL.png and the  tag is not rendering; or else you need to examine the location of your .png file.  For sure, add the quotes:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><head></head><body><img src='imagelocationURL.png'/></body></html>"
```

Then, try hardcoding the path to your .png file and see if that works:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><head></head><body><img src='C:/Temp/imagelocationURL.png'/></body></html>"
```

If the hardcoded path works, then you just need to play around with your code to pull out the equivalent of the hardcoded path.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the content being in a file instead of passing the whole html content, you can easily achieve it by doing this:

```
if (File.Exists(filetoopen))
                this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format(filetoopen));
```